# Clone only if non-empty

Tags: git

Normally, `git clone` is happy to clone empty repositories, it just prints the warning

> warning: You appear to have cloned an empty repository.

Is there any way to tell git to clone only non-empty repositories? Ideally, I would prefer `git clone` to simply fail (without creating a working copy) if the repository is empty.

My current solution is in three steps: (1) clone, (2) see if the clone is empty, (3) delete if it is empty. Does the job but hardly elegant (and it prints warnings that I will need to filter out). Is there a more straightforward solution?

Comment: How often do you find yourself in this situation?  There's nothing intrinsically wrong with cloning an empty repository (e.g., maybe you create a new repository on github, then clone it and populate it locally before pushing things back up).

Comment: @larsks: This is for automation in large organisations with large numbers of Git users and repositories. I need to have clones of non-empty repos (and only them) locally available.

Answer (score 1):

There is not really a way to do that, but you could approximate it (somewhat poorly): set up a remote pointing to the repo you might clone, and then run `git ls-remote` on that remote.  (You can do this with any git repository, including a temporary empty one.)  If ls-remote finds no refs, cloning that repository would have created an empty repository.

There are two major defects with this method, and one minor:

1. You need a place to add the test remote and do the ls-remote.
2. This is as just much work as actually cloning the empty repository.  You save time when compared to cloning a large *non*-empty repository, but you will do that (clone the non-empty repo) anyway.
3. (Minor) The answer you get is, at least potentially, out of date by the time you get it.  This is also true of cloning a repo and discovering that it's empty (maybe fetching will now find a non-empty repository), or even of cloning or fetching some other repository: by the time you get and inspect the result, which might be several whole *seconds* after you start the process, there could be dozens or even thousands of new commits added to the remote repo (this depends on how active the repository is).

I think you might as well just clone-and-maybe-remove, really.  (Or just clone and *don't* remove: there's nothing wrong with an empty repo.  I see from a comment that you don't want them; I just don't see the reason *why* you don't want them.  "For automation" is a purpose, but not a reason.)